# Trouble with wp_enqueue_script

Tags: wp-enqueue-script

Is the following correct? Any help would be much appreciated.  Thanks

```
<?php

//sidedish slide script
function sidedish_slide_script() {

    wp_register_script('add-sd-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/form-slider/jquery-1.8.2.min.js', array('jquery'),'', true );
    wp_register_script('add-sd-custom', get_template_directory_uri() . '/form-slider/formslider.js', array('jquery'),'', true );
    wp_register_style('add-sd-css',get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/form-slider/styles.css', '','','screen' );        
    wp_enqueue_script ('add-sd-js');
    wp_enqueue_script ('add-sd-custom');
    wp_enqueue_style ('add-sd-css');    
}
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','sidedish_slide_script');

?>
```

Comment: Yea. That seems quite right. Are you facing any problem ?

Comment: What trouble are you having exactly with this?

Answer (score 0):

```
//sidedish slide script  
function sidedish_slide_script() {  

  // No need to register jquery.js  

  wp_register_script( 'add-sd-js',  
     get_theme_file_uri('/form-slider/formslider.js'),  
     array('jquery'), null, true );  

  wp_register_style( 'add-sd-css',  
    get_theme_file_uri('/form-slider/styles.css'),array(), null,'screen' );  

  wp_enqueue_script ('add-sd-custom');  
  wp_enqueue_style ('add-sd-css');  
}  
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','sidedish_slide_script');
```